# TelegramBot - Move button to new line

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

How to make the buttons be in a column, and not in a row. Example Image, as I need:
 [Click Imgur][1].

```
function sendInlineKeyboard($id_chat, $text, $array)
{
 $keyboard = array("inline_keyboard" => array($array));

        $toSend = array('method' => 'sendMessage', 'chat_id' => $id_chat, 'text' => $text, 'resize_keyboard' => true, 'reply_markup' => $keyboard);
        isset($mark) ? $toSend['parse_mode'] = $mark : '';
        isset($id_message) ? $toSend['reply_to_message_id'] = $id_message : '';     
        $ch = curl_init(API_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($toSend));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        $a = curl_exec($ch);
        return json_decode($a, true);           
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `test`");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {             
            $array[] = array('text' => $row['city'], 'callback_data' => $id);
sendInlineKeyboard($user_id, 'String', $array);
}
```

Not Working. For an answer from `0stone0`:

```
$keyboard = [
    'inline_keyboard' => [
        [
            ['text' => 'Button 1', 'callback_data' => 'someString'],
            ['text' => 'Button 2', 'callback_data' => 'someString', 'text' => 'Button 3', 'callback_data' => 'someString', 'text' => 'Button 4', 'callback_data' => 'someString'],
            ['text' => 'Button 5', 'callback_data' => 'someString']
        ]
    ]
];
$toSend = array('method' => 'sendMessage', 'chat_id' => $id_chat, 'text' => "Test", 'resize_keyboard' => true, 'reply_markup' => $keyboard);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telegram reads each array as a row.
If you wish to have multiple buttons in 1 row, add them to an array:

```
$keyboard = [
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [
            [ "B~1" ],
            [ "B~2" ]
        ],
        [
            [ "B~3" ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

Since your function gets the `array` variable thats being used as the keyboard, the 'mistake' is located elsewhere.

If you need any further help, please edit your page with the codes that calls the `sendInlineKeyboard` function.

---

*EDIT*:
I've made a small example regarding the arrays;

```
$keyboard = [
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [
            [
                "text" => "B~1",
                "callback_data" => "myCallbackData"
            ],
            [
                "text" => "B~2",
                "callback_data" => "myCallbackData"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "text" => "B~3",
                "callback_data" => "myCallbackData"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];


$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=<MY-ID>&text=<TEXT>&reply_markup=" . json_encode($keyboard);
```

[image: Exmaple]

---

Edit 2

You're asking for a 'full' width button. The screenshot you've provided shows 2 buttons, 1 in each row. My example above results in the same, if you use the correct client that will use the full screen width for the button. The first screenshot was from my telegram mac os client, using the old version, the same buttons look like this:
[image]
So, the client you are using is just showing the buttons small, it's not something you can manage. (Except using other client)

Comment: Not Working. I just need to follow the example so that the buttons are separated by columns and Button2 and 3 not displayed. Screenshot: [link](https://i.imgur.com/jrO7iCX.jpg)

Comment: See the post again. I edited it and wrote the code for you.

Comment: When writing a small example I saw that I missed the second array. Please see updated answer. I hope it helps you ;)

Comment: Thank. But please tell me how to make the full size of the button as in the screenshot? [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bld7O.jpg)

You can edit your answer as I need it.

Comment: Added some more info, please upvote/accept my answer if I've helped you in any way ;)